# Category labels having brackets([]) are not showing complete label

Tags: amcharts4

In am chart, labels having square bracket in it are ignoring the content between [] brackets on category axis . I checked and ensured that they are passed as string instead of array, even I tried to return this as html ,that also did not worked out for me

Now I am expecting the label to be shown completely irrespective of its content when it is string. Can any one suggest some ways to overcome this .Thanks in advance

My code:

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var config = {
yAxes: [
{
id: "c1",
type: "CategoryAxis",
dataFields : {
category : "country"
},
renderer : {
minGridDistance : 20,
minWidth : 120,
grid : [{
location : 0
}]
}
}
],
xAxes: [
{
id: "v1",
type: "ValueAxis",
dataFields : {
value : "visits"
},
renderer : {
maxLabelPosition : 0.98
}
}
],
series: [
{
type: "ColumnSeries",
name: "Series Title",
dataFields: {
valueX: "visits",
categoryY: "country"
},
sequencedInterpolation : true,
sequencedInterpolationDelay : 100,
adapter : {
tooltipText : function(val) {
return 'hello' + val // doesn't work?
}
},
columns : [
{
strokeOpacity : 1, // has no effect?
template : {
adapter : {
"fill" : function (fill, target) {
return target.dataItem.index // not quite right
}
}
}
}
]
}
],
cursor : {
type : "XYCursor",
behavior : "zoomY"
},
colors : {
saturation : 0.4 // does not affect colors?
}
};

var chart = am4core.createFromConfig(config, "chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
"country": "[UAS]STATES",
"visits": 3025
}, {
"country": "China",
"visits": 1882
},{
"country": "Russia",
"visits": 580
}, {
"country": "South Korea",
"visits": 443
}, {
"country": "Canada",
"visits": 441}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Brackets in amcharts are treated as reference to data.

> Basically, it goes like this: whenever amCharts 4 displays a text, it passes it via text processor we call Text formatter. During the process anything contained within curly brackets { ... } is treated as a reference to some data value and is replaced with relative data. Similarly everything that goes within square brackets [ ... ] is treated as text formatting options, and again is not displayed but rather parsed for text styling instructions.

To solve your issue you need to escape brackets, like so:

> country: "[[UAS]]STATES",

Take a look in Docs:
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-strings/#Escaping